# Automate the process of logging PDF files with associated information

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a database that has a userform to help automate the process of logging PDF files with associated information.

For this I want to have the user enter in the drawings information, browse for the folder the drawings are in, and then have the drawing files listed in Excel with the information repeated for each drawing/PDF entry.

How should I code this?

This is what I have currently (and it doesn't work):

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub startIt()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

    InitialFoldr$ = "G:\ScannedDwgArchive\Transportation and BuildingsDrawings\Rocky Harbour\"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
        .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
        .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End If
    End With

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(InitialFoldr$)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 21), Address:= _
        File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Name
        i = i + 1
        Call TextboxWrite
    Next
End Sub

**Sheet 5 is the page in my workbook I am working on. This part of the code never works**
Sub TextboxWrite()
    Sheet5.Range(i, 12) = jobNumTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 15) = TownTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 16) = YearTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 18) = StreetTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 19) = PhaseTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 20) = cdTextBox.value
End Sub
```

I can open the folder, and have the files written to Excel. And that is about it. How can I make this to work?

UPDATE: I got it to work after some of your guidance and some new found tutorials. Here it is (not finished, but it's functional)

```
Sub Button2_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub startIt()

  Dim FileSystem As Object
  Dim HostFolder As String
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

  InitialFoldr$ = "G:\ScannedDwgArchive\Transportation and Buildings Drawings\Rocky Harbour\"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End If
    End With

  Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(InitialFoldr$)

End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    Dim i As Integer                             ' DECLARE i VARIABLE
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).row + 1
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 21), Address:= _
        File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Name
        i = i + 1
        Call TextboxWrite(i)                     ' PASS ARGUMENT

    Next
End Sub

Sub TextboxWrite(i As Integer)                   ' RECEIVE ARGUMENT
    Worksheets("CIVIL DATABASE").Activate
    Dim row As Integer
    row = i - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 12) = UserForm1.jobNumTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 15) = UserForm1.TownTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 16) = UserForm1.YearTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 17) = UserForm1.descTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 18) = UserForm1.StreetTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 19) = UserForm1.PhaseTextBox.value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 20) = UserForm1.cdTextBox.value

End Sub
```

Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: When you run your code, where does it give an error? (If there is no error what is the last line that worked correctly?). I don't understand why there is a line about hyperlinks either, are the files listed in Excel supposed to hyperlink to the folder location? If yes, is it the folder location that was chosen with the file dialog?

Comment: The hyperlinks part was from a tutorial that would extract file names and print them to the cells in the next free cell. I am not using hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `i` value to the called subroutine, `TextboxWrite()`. Right now, `i` has no value in its scope since it is not a global variable but a local one:

```
...
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    Dim i As Integer                             ' DECLARE i VARIABLE
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 21), Address:= _
        File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Name
        i = i + 1
        Call TextboxWrite(i)                     ' PASS ARGUMENT
    Next
End Sub

Sub TextboxWrite(i As Integer)                   ' RECEIVE ARGUMENT
    Sheet5.Range(i, 12) = jobNumTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 15) = TownTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 16) = YearTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 18) = StreetTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 19) = PhaseTextBox.value
    Sheet5.Range(i, 20) = cdTextBox.value
End Sub
```

Also, for best practices in VBA, use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) on the top line outside any subroutine or function. This forces you to declare every variable used when you compile code (Debug \ Compile) before macro execution which hopefully is a regular practice. Additionally, anticipate runtime errors with [`On Error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx) handling. If you incorporate `Err.Number` and `Err.Description` you will receive more detailed information on the issue.

Comment: I now have two errors (getting closer). 1. `Option Explicit` doesn't let the code run, says that I can only have comments after end subs. 2. At `Sheet5.Range(i, 12) = jobNumTextBox.value` I receive "Run-time error 424 Object Required".

Comment: Heed `Option Explicit` as I do not see all your code. Hopefully you didn't actually use the ellipsis here `...` (meant to reuse above code). Also, unless this code is behind a userform you must qualify the textbox with name of UserForm as you did in working answer. It seems this solved your immediate issue. Please accept to confirm resolution.